# SWI-prolog trace: is not explain in English

Tags: swi-prolog

Why it explains in different languages? How to set to English?

[image: swi-prolog trace minimum value of a list]

Comment: Please don't post images for things that you could post in plain-tekst. I for one cannot see images on this computer. It sounds like the image is from a tracelog, which is just text. A code block seems more appropriate for that.

Comment: If you are using SWI-Prolog-Editor, what is your language file set to? `Options` tab on config dialog, accessible from `Windows` menu.

Comment: ok, just because i haven't understood yet about swi-porlog, and just a starter. but i really want to know deeper about Prolog.